# create a function that give the output coordinate pixel of an image using a transformation

Tags: image, matlab, math, image-processing

I am using `imwarp` function on Matlab to transform a image with respect of a transformation.
You can see the result in the picture below : 
[image]

My goal is to create a function where in input I give a coordinate of the left picture (in pixels) and it returns me in output the coordinate of the same point but in the right picture...

Does someone know if `imwarp` function calculate the corresponding coordinate one by one... I don't get how it works!

Comment: you mean **imwarp** I guess... which part of [Understanding What Happens in Geometric Transformation](http://example.com) and [imwarp](http://example.com) is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the [transformation object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html#inputarg_tform) that you pass to `imwarp` to convert any pixel coordinate to it's new transformed location

```
image = imread('cameraman.tif');

% Create a transformation object
tform = affine2d([1 0 0; .5 1 0; 0 0 1]);

% Warp the image using this transformation
[transformed_image, RB] = imwarp(image, tform);

% Transform pixel coordinates to new coordinates using tform
[xw, yw] = tform.transformPointsForward(100, 100);

% Display the points and transformed points
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(image, []);
hold on
plot(100, 100, 'r*')

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(transformed_image, []);
hold on
plot(xw, yw, 'r*');
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you for answering! Just you are doing the opposite than me. My original is the transformed picture (a wrong square due to the perspective) and my final transformed is the normal square image. So when I applied you code I have the wrong result. Where you enter (100, 100) for input, I would like to give some coordinate of the "transformed picture" (which is the original for me...) - @Suever - Thank you ans hope I are clear!